# Containers unable to communicate on same EC2 host

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs, docker-network

I have a multi-container application deployed on an EC2 instance via a single ECS task. When I try making an HTTP request to container-2 from container-1, I get error "Name or service not known."

I'm unable to reproduce this locally when I run with docker compose. I'm using the bridge network mode. I've SSH'd into the EC2 instance and can see that both containers are on the bridge network. (I've unsuccessfully tried awsvpc as well and that led to a different set of issues... so I'll save that for a separate post if necessary.)

Here's a snippet of my task-definition.json:

```
{
    ...
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "container-1",
            "image": "container-1",
            "portMappings": [
              {
                "hostPort": 8081,
                "containerPort": 8081,
                "protocol": "tcp"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "container-2",
            "image": "container-2",
            "portMappings": [
              {
                "hostPort": 8080,
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "tcp"
              }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    ...
}
```

**EDIT1 - Adding some of my ifconfig, let me know if I need to add more.**

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:a7ff:febd:55df  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:a7:bd:55:df  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 842  bytes 55315 (54.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 614  bytes 78799 (76.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ecs-bridge: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.172.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::c5a:1bff:fed4:525f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 1890 (1.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3760  bytes 274480 (268.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3760  bytes 274480 (268.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**EDIT2 - docker inspect bridge**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "...",
        "Created": "...",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "XXX",
                    "Gateway": "XXX"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "somehash": {
                "Name": "container-1",
                "EndpointID": "XXX",
                "MacAddress": "XXX",
                "IPv4Address": "XXX",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "somehash": {
                "Name": "container-2",
                "EndpointID": "XXX",
                "MacAddress": "XXX",
                "IPv4Address": "XXX",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: show us ifconfig output(on EC2).

Comment: @RichardRublev added partial output to post

Comment: docker inspect ecs-bridge

Comment: @RichardRublev I think you mean docker inspect bridge? Both containers are shown.

Comment: can you docker exec -it container1 bash,and then try ping container2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow containers in a single task, in EC2 host networking mode, to communicate with each other you need to specify the `links` attribute to map containers to internal network names. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_network).

Comment: I'm confused why this is necessary. This says "without the need for port mappings" -- I have port mappings. Weren't links deprecated years ago?

Comment: Links worked. Though my question still remains...